# How can I make a series of divs repeat in a container?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of thumbnails in a container.

When the person scrolls through the container, how can I make the thumbnails repeat so there is no beginning or end?

**HTML**:

```
<p>How can you make this repeat</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/Zpkrax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is possible with pure CSS, what you could do however is use javascript.

If you're open to use a library, I recommend [**Flickity**](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/), which is pretty easy to set up with your current markup.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.container');
var flkty = new Flickity(elem, {
  // options
  cellAlign: 'left',
  wrapAround: true,
  contain: true
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.0.5/dist/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.0.5/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<p>How can you make this repeat</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Make sure to check the different kind of licence **[here](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/license.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to require some javascript. I wouldn't recommend trying to code this behavior from scratch; google `infinite scrolling js library` and see what you can find.

Answer (score 0):

You need js for this Infinite Scroll.
Here are the 6 examples of Infinite scroll you can download from there. Hope this link help you.

https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos